# Locally closed irreducible subset of an affine scheme.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, affine-schemes

I'm self-studying some Algebraic Geometry and I have the following question.
Let us take $X=\operatorname{Spec}A$, where $A$ is a commutative ring. I am trying to show that every locally closed irreducible subset of $X$ contains an unique generic point.

This is what I've been thinking so far:

Let $Y$ be our irreducible, locally closed subset. We know that $q=I(Y) = \bigcap_{p \in Y} p$ is a prime ideal, I believe we would be done if we could show that $q \in Y$. Let us write $Y = V(\mathfrak{a}) \cap U$, for $U$ open. If $U$ would happen to be a principal open, of the form $D(f)$, then $Y = V(\mathfrak{a}) \cap U$ could be written as $\operatorname{Spec}B$ where $B = A_f / \mathfrak{a}A_f$. In this case, to say that Spec B is irreducible would simply mean that it had an unique minimal prime, which of course would have to lie in $\operatorname{Spec}B$. I feel uneasy about this argument, and I'm not totally sure if it is correct. However, if it is done in this special case, how could it be used to show the general case?
I guess we could argue from our special case if we wrote $Y = V(\mathfrak{a}) \cap  (\bigcup_i D(f_i)) = \bigcup_i (V(\mathfrak{a}) \cap D(f_i))$,  but I'm not sure.

So, I am very grateful for any help here, and answers on how to tackle this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Write $Y=\bar Y\cap U$ where "bar" means closure in the topological space $X$ and $U\subset X$ is some open set.

**Existence of generic point**
 Since $Y$ is irreducible, so is $\bar Y$.
 Therefore $\bar Y$ has a generic point $\eta$ and $\bar{ \lbrace \eta\rbrace }=\bar Y$.
Of course $\eta\in Y$, else we would have $\bar{ \lbrace \eta\rbrace }=\bar Y\subset X\setminus U$ and thus $\overline { Y}\cap Y=\emptyset$, an absurd statement.
Thus $\eta$ is a generic point for  $Y$ since its closure *in $Y$* is $\bar Y\cap Y=Y$.

**Uniqueness  of generic point**
If $\eta'$ were another generic point of $Y$, its closure in $X$ would also be $\bar Y$.
But an irreducible closed subset of a scheme has only one generic point, hence $ \eta'=\eta$ .

**Edit: Warning !**
If $Y \subset X=Spec(\mathbb Z)$ is the complement of the generic point $\eta=(0)\in Spec(\mathbb Z)$, then $Y$ is an  irreducible subspace of $X$.  However $Y$ has no generic point!
The explanation of this apparent contradiction to the above  is that $Y$ is *not* locally closed in $X$.

Comment: Dear @Georges Elencwajg, do I understand it right that for every scheme $X$ the points of the topological space $|X|$ are in one-to-one correspondence with the irreducible subsets of the topological space $|X|$? (I know that this is true for affine $X$). Thank you.

Comment: Dear @GeorgesElencwajg, sorry but now I am confused: If you consider the scheme $X=\mathbb{A}^1_\mathbb{C}=\operatorname{Spec}(\mathbb{C}[X])$ then it is irreducible and hence $|X|$ has just one irreducible component. But certainly $|X|$ has more points, for example the maximal ideal $m=(X-1)$ corresponds to the closed point $\{m\}$ (which is an irreducible subset of $|X|$).

Comment: Dear @user8463524: Sorry, I was mixing things up in my preceding (now deleted) comment to you. The correct statement is that there is a bijection between $\vert X \vert$ and the set of **closed irreducible** subsets of $\vert X \vert$. That bijection associates to $x$ its closure $\overline {\{x\}}$ and the inverse bijection asociates to the closed irreducible subset $Y\subset \vert X \vert$ its unique generic point $y$.

Answer (score 0):

We use the order reversing bijective correspondence between closed subsets and radical ideals multiple times.

Let $V(I)$ be an irreducible closed subset, where $I$ is a radical ideal. Let $J,K$ be any ideals, if $JK\subset I$, then $V(I)\subset V(JK)=  V(J)\cup V(K)$. Therefore we have the decomposition of
$$V(I) = \left(V(I)\cap V(J)\right) \bigcup \left(V(I)\cap V(K)\right).$$ 
By irreducibility, we must have WLOG $V(I) = V(I)\cap V(J)$, that is $V(I)\subset V(J)$. From here we pass to the radical and conclude that $J\subset \sqrt{J}\subset \sqrt{I} = I$.

Using similar argument we can see easily that if $I$ is prime, then $V(I)$ is an irreducible closed subset. Therefore we have a bijection between irreducible closed subsets and prime ideals, which are points of the affine scheme.