# What is the local ring of a scheme $X$ along a subvariety $V$: $\mathcal{O}_{V,X}$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, schemes, local-rings

I am trying to learn about scheme theoretic algebraic geometry, because I actually want to study the basics of interseciton theory. I stumbled across the term "local ring $\mathcal{O}_{V,X}$ of a scheme $X$ along a closed subscheme/subvariety/primedivisor $V$" many times but I just can't find a definition of this term in my textbooks on schemes. (I have looked at Bosch, Eisenbud & Harris, FOAG by Vakil,...)

I am sure they explain it but I just don't see it. Could anybody help me out here?

Comment: $V$ as a subvariety has a unique generic point. Consider the local ring with respect to that point.

Comment: So every irreducible closed subset $V$ of a scheme admits a unique generic point $x$. The only local ring I can thing of would be the stalk $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ at $x$. Is this what is meant by $\mathcal{O}_{V,X}$? Does this also have a different name?

Comment: Yes, see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1155342/). Yes, I think it is what is meant by $\mathcal O_{V, X}$. I don't know of other names though. BTW, a space in which every irreducible closed subspace has a unique generic point is said to be sober. Consider the [lemma](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01IS) from Stacks Project 01IS.

Comment: @awllower You are correct - would you care to record your comments as an answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1155342/), or by [Stacks Project Lemma 01IS](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01IS), every irreducible closed subspace of a scheme has a unique generic point, i.e. the topological space underlying a scheme is *sober*. I think by the local ring $\mathcal O_{V, X}$ of a scheme $X$ along a sub-variety $V$ is meant the local ring $\mathcal O_{X, x}$ of $X$ with respect to the unique generic point $x$ of $V$.

---

Hope this helps.