# Show that in a quasi-compact scheme every point has a closed point in its closure, via Zorn's lemma

Tags: algebraic-geometry, solution-verification, schemes

It's the same question in [Show that in a quasi-compact scheme every point has a closed point in its closure](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/646995/show-that-in-a-quasi-compact-scheme-every-point-has-a-closed-point-in-its-closur).

> Show that in a quasi-compact scheme $X$, every point $p$ has a closed point in its closure

So here I want to ask for a solution verification. At first I did it wrong, without using the quasicompact properties. And after hours of trying I got a proof via Zorn's lemma, as following.

Proof: Suppose $p \in X$, define $\Sigma = \{Z: \text{nonempty, closed, and } \subseteq \overline{\{q\}} \}$. Then $\Sigma$ is nonempty for $\overline{\{q\}} \in \Sigma$. Define a partial order on $\Sigma$ by the subset containing relationship, i.e., $a \leq b$ if and only if $a \subseteq b$.

Then every descending chain chain has a lower bound: Suppose $\cdots \leq Z_n \leq \cdots \leq Z_1$, i.e, $\cdots \subseteq Z_n \subseteq \cdots \subseteq Z_1$. Then $\cap Z_n$ cannot be empty. Otherwise we have $X=X-\cap Z_n = \cup (X-Z_n)$. Then by $X$ being quasicompact, some subcover of $\{Z_n\}$ covers $X$. WLOG suppose it's $\{X-Z_1, \cdots, X-Z_n\}$. Then $X = \cup_{i=1}^{n} (X-Z_i) = X - Z_n$. Hence $Z_n$ is empty. It contradicts with the assumption that $Z_n$ is not empty. Hence $\cap Z_n$ is not empty and hence a lower bound for the descending chain.

Now every descending chain has a lower bound. By Zorn's lemma, $\Sigma$ has some minimal element $m$. We prove that $m$ is a single point set $\{q\}$ and hence $q$ is a  closed point contained in $\overline{\{p\}}$:

Since $\overline{\{q\}} \subseteq m$. By $m$ being minimal, we have $\overline{\{q\}} = m$. If there is some other point $q' \in m$, for the same argument we have $\overline{\{q'\}} = m$. Then by Vakil's FOAG, 5.1.B Exercise, [there is a bijection between irreducible closed subsets and points for scheme](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1155342/irreducible-closed-subsets-of-a-scheme-corresponds-to-points). We have $q = q'$. $\square$

Is this proof correct? In general I got the idea from the proof for affine scheme. It differs with the linked answer and uses the result of another Exercise(cf Exercise 5.1.B in Vakil's FOAG). I am afraid if I still make something wrong. more related context can be found in [Vakil's FOAG August 29, 2022 Edition, Page 155](http://math.stanford.edu/%7Evakil/216blog/FOAGaug2922publici.pdf).
Thank you very much.

Comment: Yeah, it works! (Modulo some confusion concerning the names of the points $p$ and $q$.) Alternatively, you can use the points in the closure of the point ordered by the [specialization order](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/specialization+order). Notice that a point is closed iff it is minimal for the specialization order, so Zorn's lemma gives you the conclusion directly if you can show the hypothesis is satisfied.

Comment: (Just something that I'm not sure is clear from the way you wrote the proof: the chain has transfinite length in general, not countable.)

Comment: @Dabouliplop Ah here I did mean a countable chain. I have never noticed that the chain in the hypothesis of Zorn’s lemma can be transfinite. Luckily the proof seems requiring no change in the general case. The intersection still works.

Comment: @Dabouliplop Thank you for pointing out via the specialization order. Taking any point from the intersection of the closures gives a lower bound. It’s much direct. And it seems even not requiring the space is a scheme, only requiring the quasicompact property? That’s saying, all points in a quasicompact (compact in other context) topological space has a closed point in its closure?

Comment: I got an reference from https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/005E for this. It stills requiring $X$ is $T_0$/Kolmogorov, which is holded by schemes. My last comment mistook the specialization order as a partial order, which in fact is just a preorder in general.

Comment: Yeah, it's important that the length can be uncountable. Otherwise the first uncountable ordinal would be a counter-example to Zorn's lemma. You're welcome!